# C#: Why does the user have to press enter before Console.Readline() will begin reading?

Tags: c#, console-application

My program can be run with the GUI or from the command line. When it is run from the command line, I ask for more commands once the program has started (using Console.Readline()). However, it will not accept any input from the user until they press Enter (BEFORE they type their input).

I start the project as a console project as so:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool AllocConsole();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool AttachConsole(int pid);

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "noGUI")
    {
        if (!AttachConsole(-1))
        {
            AllocConsole();
        }
    ...

        List<string> newInput;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write(@"Enter additional commands: ");
            string inputStr = Console.ReadLine();

            newInput = GetArgs(inputStr);

            if (newInput.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Please enter a valid command");
                continue;
            }
            ...
        } while(true)
    }
...
```

Which outputs the below when the user enters "/Exit" (for example):

> **Enter additional commands:** /Exit
>
> **'/Exit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.**

However, if the user first presses Enter (right after "Enter additional commands: "), they can enter commands for the program fine.

Any idea on why they must press enter first? It is not intuitive for the user to press it before they type, so I would like to change it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you attached to the console of the command line processor, cmd.exe.  Now there are *two* programs that are interested in input.  Cmd.exe wins, it doesn't know what the /Exit command is supposed to mean.  And displays the error message you saw.  No problem when you press Enter first, cmd.exe doesn't mind that.  And your program gets a turn.

Create your own console, always call AllocConsole().

Comment: Ah I understand what you are saying, thank you for clearing that up!  P.S. Is there no easy way to keep it all in the same console?

Comment: There is, you have to start your program differently.  Use `start /wait yourapp.exe`.  That blocks cmd.exe until your app exits, you have the console all to yourself.  Meh on practical.

Comment: This was a cool puzzle btw. +1 on the question, you documented it very well.

Answer (score 0):

Because [Enter] signifies the end of the line!

If you don't like that, just use `Console.ReadKey()` or `Console.Read()` instead.

Comment: -1 the question wasn't about avoiding pressing enter, its about having to press enter before the readline picks anything up